# node.js, pg module and done() method

Tags: node.js, node.js-pg

Using the `pg` module and clients pool I need to call `done()` method in order to return the client into clients pool.

Once I connect to the server, I add SQL query client’s query queue and I start handling the result asynchronously row by row in row event:

```
// Execute SQL query
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM categories");
// Handle every row asynchronously
query.on('row', handleRow );
```

When I should call `done()` method?
Should I call it once I receive the `end` event and all rows are processed or I can call it immediately after I add SQL query to the client’s query queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from an example on this project's page (https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query-stream), I'd recommend calling it when you get the `end` event.

This makes sense, because you're not `done` with it until you're received the last row.  If someone else got that same connection and tried using it, that would likely create odd errors.

Answer (score 1):

The former makes sense: you would want to call it once you know you have processed all rows for your query.

```
// your DB connection info
var conString = "pg://admin:admin@localhost:5432/Example";

var pg = require("pg");
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

// Your own query
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

query.on("row", function (row, result) {
  // do your stuff with each row
  result.addRow(row);
});

query.on("end", function (result) {
  // here you have the complete result
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, 2));
  // end when done ;)
  client.end();
});
```